# Just html/js or a mix with server sided code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Intro**

I'm struggling with a choice i have to make. We have to build a somewhat complex html application which will be using
alot of dynamic stuff like jQuery's sortables, and other nifty html5 stuff. Currently we have a choice between two options.
I'll try to describe them as good as i can. I'd like to hear your opinion about it, and what option you'd go for and why.

---

**Just JS and HTML**

Create everything in javascript / html. There will be one html file which will include other parts of html files. So for example:
index.html can include menubar.html and news.html. I'll call them 'partials' from now on, like in C#.NET

This inclusion will be done through javascript. We will be using a self made template engine which will get the partial html
files through an AJAX call (jQuery). So, just an AJAX call to a html file. That way it actually reads the text inside of it. Then the read text (which is html) will be placed inside the index.html at a specified 'tag', like;
{content : menubar}

But a partial html file can also contain other 'tags' like this:

Your username:

{username}

Every partial view will belong to a 'viewmodel' (We're going to use MVVM architecture). So the template engine knows in what
model to look for this tag and will replace that tag with its corresponding value.

We will also be using a custom made observer pattern. The template engine will use the observer to update the html
automatically when a value changed in a model.

All the data that needs to be displayed will come from a server. We will connect to it through html5 sockets. The returned data
will be in JSON format.

---

**A mix of HTML/JS and PHP**

Another possibility is to use a PHP framework instead. We will use the frameworks template engine to combine all the partial html files into the index.html.
When an update occurs an AJAX call will be made to a PHP file. The PHP file will most likely return HTML data instead of JSON. Because in this case we won't be using a templating system in javascript. The HTML data will of course come from the partial html files. PHP will fill in all the required data in this partial html file.

There will still be a websocket connection though, but it will only be used to send and receive notifications.

---

**Your opinion?**

I basically would like to hear your opinion. For me, the first one sounds like a good idea. But somehow doesn't feel like it. And i don't really see how the client can gain extra benefit out of this when almost everything is done client sided. For some reason i also have the feeling more hidden problems will arise when we will walk this path.

I think the second approach would be better. To me the socket connection already is some kind of observer pattern. It notifies you when an event happened (like, another user made a change). We can also reduce the amount of JS files since alot of stuff will be done on the server.

But maybe the answer is just that it really doesn't matter which choice we make.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: don't build your own template engine, there are good alternatives. Like mustache

Comment: so in this case.. what are you making actually? you just explained stuff, mentioned methods, patterns a lot that you never mentioned what you are going to make. Is it an app that needs a database? does it involve validations and checks? Or is it a "just for show app that doesn't need server assistance? You might be over-thinking everything for a small project (been there recently, doesn't feel good at all)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. The template engine must be able to do some more specific things. I don't want to go into too much details about that here. We've looked at alot of tpl engines and mustache is one of them. I know there are some great tools out there, like knockoutjs, backbone etc. But for now just pretend we have to build some thing our selfs. Like the observer part.

Comment: @Joseph Yes it needs a database. Eventually the app will be some sort of Scrum board. So you can drag and drop tasks. You must be notified when someone changes a task or adds a note to it. Things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, there you go, just the explanation I needed. By the way that it sounds, i assume you know what to do in your data communication from client to server and back. You should use JSON as much as possible.

anyways, I suggest you build your app with the least amount of server processing as possible. leave those processing for the validations, session checks and stuff. for those things that don't change, leave them static, like the templates. doing too much on the server adds to the "waiting time" and clients don't like that.

what i did in my project was to lazy load and cache my templates, not just by browser cache, but in an object within my framework (didn't know how to use local storage yet). every time i needed a template, i looked at an object in my framework. if that template isn't there, request it via ajax, store it and use it. I used Mustache by the way, very handy. This way, it won't bog down your initial load. Incremental loading is good.

as for your architecture, i can't really say anything about the MVVM, but i know module-sandbox-core pattern.

overall, it's more like option 1 for me - go client side! but mind best practices and optimization always. test and profile your code. also, don't forget to minify the templates during production, as well as use compression during transmission (Gzip).

Comment: Decision is made. Will be the first option. Seems to be the best option after all, like you said. Can't vote up though, not enough points for that :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is SEO important?  If so use server side scripts like PHP to build your HTML.

Comment: you can load initial, basic content, then just add-on the "eye-candy" stuff